# use fontawesome to show facebook, twitter and instagram images just before a text

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-awesome

I am trying to do very simple thing but I am not sure how I can do that.. I have this [nav-image](https://s13.postimg.org/kw5877j93/Capture.png) which is exactly same as my left navigation where top portion is little bit transparent and bottom is black image. Here is my jsfiddle where you can see my left navigation: https://jsfiddle.net/g2ahx6nq/12/

So on the left nav bar I want to put few things just above the line where black image is getting started -  exactly as I have in that image link. I have added below line below the div but it's not getting shown at the right spot:

```
<ul>
    <li><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" style="float:left"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-twitter-square" style="float:left"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-instagram" style="float:left"></i></li>
</ul>

<a class="login" href="#">Log In&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp|</a> 
<a class="login" href="#">Sign Up</a>
```

And also how can we get corresponding facebook, twitter and instagram image just above `Log In | Sign up` text. I believe we need to use [fontawesome](http://fontawesome.io/examples/) here but I am confuse because I am using that as well but still it doesn't work for me. Any thoughts of how I can do exactly same thing which is at the bottom in my nav-image link.

Comment: did you include the css file from fontawesome  in your headers?

Comment: in the actual code I do have it. This is what I have: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-awesome.min.css">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited to close the white gap.** (noted in `.company-bio` CSS) - tweak values to your benefit.

Also added a few classes here and there, they are noted in the CSS as well.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

p,
span,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
td,
div,
ul,
li {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}


/* added classes */

.login {
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
  z-index: 9999;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.signup {
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
  z-index: 9999;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.above {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: -60px;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.fa {
  color: white;
  margin: 5px;
}


/* end added classes */

img {
  /* Set max width to be 100% of the containing element */
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

body .company-bio p {
  font-family: 'agenda';
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  letter-spacing: .18em;
  font-family: 'agenda';
  font-weight: 400;
  color: rgb(254, 254, 255);
}

div.company-bio {}

body .company-bio {
  /* added these to close gap */
  position: relative;
  top: -42px;
  /* end new */
  padding-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 131px;
  /*Added Just now */
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  max-width: 100%;
  background: url("https://s30.postimg.org/l04wudgs1/grey-bar.png");
  padding-left: 140px;
  padding-right: 155px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Adelle PE";
}

.top h1 {
  color: #f86d2c;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 37px;
}

.top p {
  color: white !important;
  background-color: black;
}

.mission-statements .programs {
  position: relative;
  top: 60px;
  width: 300px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 19px;
  border-color: #EF7440;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 25px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-shadow: 1.5px 2.598px 7.65px rgba(40, 40, 41, 0.16);
  font-family: "adelle regular";
  color: rgb(40, 40, 41);
  line-height: 1.979;
}

.top h4 {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: "ITC Avant Garde Gothic";
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 1.792;
  text-align: left;
  -moz-transform: matrix( 1.65479981820633, 0, 0, 1.66565153423699, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: matrix( 1.65479981820633, 0, 0, 1.66565153423699, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: matrix( 1.65479981820633, 0, 0, 1.66565153423699, 0, 0);
  position: absolute;
  left: 684.247px;
  top: 280.77px;
}

.top h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 320px;
  left: 450px;
  letter-spacing: .3em;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 1.6;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0px 3px 6.37px rgba(40, 40, 41, 0.004);
}

body .northmanwild .title {
  /* background-image:url(assets/img/Uploads/insta-pics.png); */
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 37px;
  margin-top: 0px !important;
  margin-bottom: 0px !important;
  font-family: "Adelle PE";
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  line-height: 1.979;
  text-align: center;
  /*text-shadow: 1.5px 2.598px 7.65px rgba(40, 40, 41, 0.5);
opacity: 100%;
fill: 57%;
*/
}

div.leftBar-bottom {
  background-image: url("https://s17.postimg.org/yvv4w2gmn/nav-background.png");
  float: left;
}

div.northmanwild {
  margin-top: -2px;
  width: 90.1%;
  float: right;
  opacity: 0.8;
  margin-bottom: -7px;
}

body .footer {
  width: 90.3%;
  float: right;
  color: rgb(40, 40, 41);
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(assets/img/Uploads/footer-bg.png);
}


/*FIGURE OUT PROBLEM WITH MISSION STATEMENTS*/

body .mission-statements {
  margin-left: 131px;
  padding-bottom: 130px;
  padding-left: 45px;
  padding-right: 45px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(assets/img/Uploads/bg-trees.png);
}

body .mission-statements .why {
  padding-top: 40px;
  font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  position: relative;
  left: -40px;
  top: 30px;
}

body .mission-statements .how {
  padding-top: 40px;
  font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

body .mission-statements .what {
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  left: -40px;
  top: 30px;
}

body .mission-statements .why pre {
  padding-left: 40px;
}

body .mission-statements .how {
  margin-top: 0px !important;
  padding-right: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}


/*.top .imgB1
{
  position: relative;
  top: -225px;
}

*/

.top {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-bottom: -7px;
}

.imgA1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.clippedmain {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#clippedImg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

#clipimgA1 {
  /*Chrome,Safari*/
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(1px 100%, 131px 100%, 130px 0px, 0px 0px);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0.5;
}


/*Firefox*/

clip-path: url("#clipPolygon");

/* iOS support inline encoded svg file*/

-webkit-mask: url(data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8;base64,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) no-repeat;

}
.imgB1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -65px;
  left: 70px;
}
.footer .footer-section1 {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
}
.footer .footer-section2 .block-title {
  position: relative;
  width: 338px;
  left: -140px;
  font-size: 16px !important;
  font-family: "AvantGarde";
  color: rgb(40, 40, 41);
  /* font-style: italic; */
  
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
}
.footer .footer-section2 .block-content {
  font-style: italic;
  line-height: 1.52;
  top: 18px;
  left: 52px;
  position: relative;
}
.footer .footer-section3 .block-content {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1.52;
  left: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  top: 15px;
  font-style: italic;
}
.footer .footer-section3 .block-title {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
  width: 60%;
  left: 14px;
  position: relative;
}
.footer .footer-section1 .block-content {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1.52;
  top: 67px;
  left: 125px;
  font-style: italic;
}
.footer .footer-section2 {
  position: relative;
  left: -89px;
}
.footer .footer-section2 {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
}
.footer .footer-section3 {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
}
.scroll-down {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in 3s;
  transition: all .5s ease-in 3s;
}
.scroll-down {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 28px;
  left: 55%;
  margin-left: -16px;
  display: block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background-size: 14px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-animation: bounce 2s infinite 2s;
  animation: bounce 2s infinite 2s;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in;
  transition: all .2s ease-in;
}
.scroll-down:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 8px);
  left: calc(50% - 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  display: block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  content: "";
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-width: 0px 0 2px 2px;
}
section.ok {
  position: relative;
  top: 2000px;
}
.copy-rights {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  top: 48px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(40, 40, 41);
  font-style: italic;
  -moz-transform: matrix( 0.99963252426166, 0, 0, 0.99882633931212, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: matrix( 0.99963252426166, 0, 0, 0.99882633931212, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: matrix( 0.99963252426166, 0, 0, 0.99882633931212, 0, 0);
  font-style: normal;
}
#leftBar {
  background-color: #030303;
  box-shadow: 2.996px 0.157px 7.65px 1.35px rgba(40, 40, 41, 0.25);
  border-right: solid #EF7440;
  border-right-width: 4px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 2278px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 131px;
  /*Commented today */
  /* opacity: 0.5;  */
}

/*

#holder {
  width: 700px;
   margin-left: 263px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
  position: fixed;

}

*/
@font-face {
  font-family: BEBAS;
  src: url("http://webdesigncove.com/fonts/BEBAS___.ttf")
}
h1.logo {
  font-size: 26px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  letter-spacing: -3px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
h1.postTitle {
  font-family: BEBAS, Helvetica, Verdana, Sans-Serif;
}
p {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  letter-spacing: .28em;
  line-height: 1.45em;
}
#navigation {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}
#navigation li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#navigation a:link {
  font-family: "ITC Avant Garde Gothic";
  font-size: 15px;
  font-style: normal;
}
#navigation a:visited {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
#navigation a:hover {
  color: #FE5B1F;
}
.copy-right-text {
  font: Bold 12px 'Open Sans';
  color: #ffffff;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="top">
  <img id="clipimgA1" class="clippedmain" src="https://s28.postimg.org/tkwg9tmdp/homepage-image-1.png" alt="img">
  <img class="imgA1" src="https://s28.postimg.org/tkwg9tmdp/homepage-image-1.png">
</div>
<div id="leftBar">
  <br />
  <svg id="clippedImg" width="0" height="0">
        <clipPath id="clipPolygon">
            <polygon points="1 100%,131 100%,130 0,0 0">
            </polygon>
        </clipPath>
    </svg>
  <ul id="navigation">
    <li><a href="#">Text1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Text2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Text3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Text4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<ul class="above">
  <li><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i></li>
  <li><i class="fa fa-twitter-square"></i></li>
  <li><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></li>
</ul>
<a class="login" href="#">Log In&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|</a>
<a class="signup" href="#">Sign Up</a>
<div class="leftBar-bottom">

</div>

<!-- End Side bar div-->
<div class="company-bio">
  <p align="center" style="font-family: Adelle PE">Hello World </p>
  <p align="center" style="font-family: Adelle PE">Nice Text! </p>
  <p align="center">Hello David</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks good mostly but as you can see I can see some white spaces between grey box and other image. That was not there before. Any idea why that is coming suddenly bcoz of this change? I mean if I remove this facebook, twitter and instgram and login/signup stuff then there is no line breks with whitespace between those two divs.. But somehow with this change, it is coming like that.

Comment: Yes sure, give me a few minutes I'll try to adjust it, you want no white space whatsoever or exactly the same space it shows on your original fiddle?

Comment: Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g2ahx6nq/11/), exactly like that. There is no spaces between them but this fiddle doesn't have that facebook,  twitter and instagram stuff. With your suggestion I will get that.

Comment: It still has right? And everything went up/down in that fiddle?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144705/discussion-between-david-and-syden).